# Azure B2C login screen error disappears due to reload

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have custom policy in my b2c with customized UI (i.e. removed signup link and added company branding) and application has deployed on server.

When I run the app, redirects to b2c login screen and If get any error due incorrect password or no account found in b2c, these error gets disappeared due to screen reload. I believe its trying to redirect as on reply url and reload same login screen.

How can I see error message and prevent login page reload so that error message doesn't get disappeared?

Comment: It could be some UI code to cause the issue. Is it possible to share the UI code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, it was reloading page because my HTML has  after removing tag its has stopped reloading page when error occurs.